# MediaWiki: Hiding drafts from Search engines without changing any file in the website directory

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, mediawiki

MediaWiki: Hiding drafts from Search engines without changing any file in the website directory,

Is this possible or **I must** change `robots.txt` for drafts starting as `draft:myDraft`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit `robots.txt` via the `MediaWiki:Robots.txt` page.

Comment: Hello and thanks Tgr. I get notified I don't have such page (`robots.txt`) unlike `commons.css` or `common.js` which I do have and can access and edit without problem.

Comment: Also Tgr, you might want to answer on this hard problem here: 22 people saw it already and one week with no answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1423571/mediawiki-how-to-delete-the-about-page

Comment: Well you don't, until you create it.

Comment: I see, so Google just expects to find it **first** and it has **nothing** to do with any CMS (MW/WP/Drupal); good to know that, thank you.

Comment: <yourwikidomain>/robots.txt is generated dynamically by MedaWiki; the contents of MediaWiki:Robots.txt (if the page exists) are included in it. There are a bunch of other ways to get stuff in there, instruct robots with meta tags etc, but MediaWiki:Robots.txt is probably the easiest when you want to blacklist by namespace (that is, URL prefix).